# RSelenium and rvest - only getting data for selected check boxes

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I can access a webpage using the following:

Data/code:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4536L)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

zona_url_to_get = "https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/eixample/l"

remDr$navigate(zona_url_to_get)


# accept cookies 
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",'/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/footer/div/button[2]')$clickElement()
#click on Distrito
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div')$clickElement()


html_zona_full_page = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()
```

This opens up the page, accepts the cookies, clicks the drop down menu and read the HTML from the page.

I can then use the following:

```
Zonas_Names = html_zona_full_page %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem')
```

To give me:

```
{xml_nodeset (16)}
 [1] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Ciutat Vella" href="/es/c ...
 [2] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Eixample" href ...
 [3] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Dreta de l'Eixample" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital ...
 [4] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Fort Pienc" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/fort-pie ...
 [5] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="La Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcel ...
 [6] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="L'Antiga Esquerra de l'Eixample" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barce ...
 [7] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Sagrada Família" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/sag ...
 [8] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Sant Antoni" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/sant-an ...
 [9] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Gràcia" href="/es/comprar ...
[10] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Horta - Guinardó" href="/ ...
[11] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Les Corts" href="/es/comp ...
[12] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Nou Barris" href="/es/com ...
[13] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Sant Andreu" href="/es/co ...
[14] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Sant Martí" href="/es/com ...
[15] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Sants - Montjuïc" href="/ ...
[16] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Sarrià - Sant Gervasi" hr
```

However, I am not interested in all of the information, just the items that are selected on the webpage (or has a tick next to them). They correspond to the following:

```
<a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Dreta de l'Eixample"...
<a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Fort Pienc"...
<a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="La Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample"...

... etc.
```

My question is, how can I keep only the ticked items in the list?

I thought the following might work since it contains the `is-checked` part but it returns a xml_nodeset 0:

```
> html_zona_full_page %>% 
+   html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked')
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

I can run:

```
html_zona_full_page %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem') %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal')
```

Which gives me:

```
{xml_nodeset (16)}
 [1] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Ciutat Vella</span>
 [2] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Eixample</span>
 [3] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Dreta de l'Eixample</span>
 [4] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Fort Pienc</span>
 [5] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">La Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample</span>
 [6] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">L'Antiga Esquerra de l'Eixample</span>
 [7] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Sagrada Família</span>
 [8] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Sant Antoni</span>
 [9] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Gràcia</span>
[10] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Horta - Guinardó</span>
[11] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Les Corts</span>
[12] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Nou Barris</span>
[13] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Sant Andreu</span>
[14] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Sant Martí</span>
[15] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Sants - Montjuïc</span>
[16] <span class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal">Sarrià - Sant Gervasi</span>
```

But I am not interested in `Ciutat Vella`, `Gràcia`, `Horta` ...  `Sarrià - Sant Gervasi` since they are not ticked on the webpage.

Ultimately, I am only interested in:

```
c("Dreta de l'Eixample", "Fort Pienc", "La Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample", "L'Antiga Esquerra de l'Eixample", "Sagrada Família", "Sant Antoni")
```

Comment: Does `html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem.is-checked')` works for you?

Comment: Can also do `html_zona_full_page  %>% html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-nestedCheckboxesList-items-droppedContents') %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem-literal') %>% html_text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `.` to join the two elements

```
Zonas_Names = html_zona_full_page %>% 
  html_nodes('.re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem.is-checked')
```

-output

```
> Zonas_Names
{xml_nodeset (7)}
[1] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem--has-separator" title="Eixample" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capi ...
[2] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Dreta de l'Eixample" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/dreta-de-l-eixample/l"><div class="su ...
[3] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Fort Pienc" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/fort-pienc/l"><div class="sui-MoleculeCheckbox ...
[4] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="La Nova Esquerra de l'Eixample" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/la-nova-esquerra-de-l-eixa ...
[5] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="L'Antiga Esquerra de l'Eixample" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/l-antiga-esquerra-de-l-ei ...
[6] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Sagrada Família" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/sagrada-familia/l"><div class="sui-Molecu ...
[7] <a class="re-GeographicSearchNext-checkboxItem is-checked" title="Sant Antoni" href="/es/comprar/viviendas/barcelona-capital/sant-antoni/l"><div class="sui-MoleculeCheckb ...
```

which corresponds to the one clicked

[image]